# Is this the way to list a file in directory using node.js and jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to list a file in a directory using jade and node.js but I am not sure if below is the right way of doing it, as I receive a type error that says

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Any hint would be much appreciated

```
h1 Your tasks
p


// list all the file
ul
  for file in files
    li
      p= file
```

node.js code

```
app.get('/tasks', function(req, res){


  fs.readdir('tasks/index', function(err, data){
    res.render('tasks/index', {"files": data});
  });

});
```

update

```
app.get('/tasks', function(req, res){


  fs.readdir('tasks', function(err, data){
    res.render('tasks/index', {"files": data});
  });

});
```

error

```
500 TypeError: /path/views/tasks/index.jade:7 5| // list all the file 6| ul > 7| each file in files 8| li 9| p= file 10| Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

    5| // list all the file
    6| ul
    > 7| each file in files
    8| li
    9| p= file
    10|
    Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: You need to show the javascript code that populate's the templates `locals`, specifically that there is a property named `files` that is an array of strings. But yes, if your local data was right (it isn't) that jade should work.

Comment: can you elaborate on that, originally I thought I only need the above jade code and the fs.reddir on my app.js to make this trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, several issues:

1. You need to use `each file in files` instead of `for`
2. 'tasks/index' is being treated as both a directory and a file. It can't be both, and it's probably a file, so your `readDir` call is probably throwing an error which is why `data` (and thus `files`) is undefined.
3. fs.readDir is going to treat relative paths as relative to process.cwd whereas res.render treats relative paths relative to express's 'views' setting.
4. Ignoring the error thrown by step 3 is just making your life harder, which is why it's a bad habit.

---

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + '/views/tasks', function(error, data){
  if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
      return;
  }
  res.render('tasks/index', {"files": data});
});
```

I don't know your filesystem organization entirely, so the paths are just guesses, but the root of your problem seems to be not coding properly in terms of filesystem organization.

Comment: I update the path to be tasks and the rendering file to be /tasks/index, I assume this will render the index.jade in tasks, and list out all the file in tasks, but I am still having the same issue, I also listed the error

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, so in theory I could of do $code$fs.readdir('/views/tasks', function(err, data){$ as well right?

Comment: Again, just get the filesystem paths correct. You can use absolute paths, but it makes your code extremely unfriendly for deployment. If you use relative paths, make them relative to __dirname. Understanding paths is a truly basic, fundamental thing you should invest time in completely understanding.

Comment: what are some good resource for getting the fundamentals? I am just recently exposed to node.js for my school project

Comment: Do a web search. This looks reasonable: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_02.html